# nm - show file that declares a symbol in a .so file

Tags: shared-libraries, nm

Is it possible for `nm` to show the file that declares a symbol in a .so file? Let's say I have some file:

```
//file.cpp
int get_data();

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this file into a shared object file, `file.so`, I should get a "U" for the `get_data` symbol when I use `nm -C file.so`. Is it possible for nm to also show the file name? For larger projects it would be helpful to be able to determine what file is declaring the unresolved symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I compile this file into a shared object file, file.so, I should get a "U" for the `get_data` symbol

You are mistaken: since nothing references `get_data`, you wouldn't in fact get a `U` for it.

To answer your question: the info that `file.cpp` referenced `get_data` symbol is gone, *unless* you compiled `file.cpp` with debugging info.

If you did, you could use `objdump -dS file.so` to find that `file.cpp` is where the reference originates.